# How to return Postgres rowcount

Tags: postgresql

Getting the count of affected rows isn't hard.

```
do
$$
declare update_count int;
begin
update assembly_version set assembly_version_minor = 3 where assembly_version_major = 1;

get diagnostics update_count = row_count;

select update_count;
end;
$$
```

Never mind the update statement, the only thing you need to know about that is it changes some rows.

The interesting part is that this code won't run because Postgres won't let me use the variable `update_count` in the select clause.

How can I return the value without resorting to wrapping it all in a function and using `return update_count;`?

Comment: What do you want to return it from if there's no function call? Where do you want to use the row count? How is that block executed?

Comment: Do you just need to see the value? Or do you need to pass it to somewhere?

Comment: You can't `return` from an anonymous(`DO`) function. If you want to see the value use; `RAISE NOTICE %`, update_count;

Comment: do (without language specifier) is essentially a plpgsql function accepting no parameters and returning nothing.  You cannot do a select in there.

Comment: All true but irrelevant to the question of how to go about getting a count of affected rows. I'd rewrite the question but someone answered it.

Comment: Adrian RAISE NOTICE sounds useful for this kind of problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DO` block can't return anything. But you don't need PL/pgSQL for this.

You can put the UPDATE into a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) that returns the changed rows, then count those rows.

```
with udpated as (
  update assembly_version 
     set assembly_version_minor = 3 
  where assembly_version_major = 1
  returning *
)
select count(*)
from updated;
```

Comment: This `with name as (DML)` business, it captures a row set of the affected rows for insert or update?

Comment: @PeterWone: I have added a link to the relevant part of the manual

Comment: Pgsql supports CTEs? Thank you, that's going to be immensely useful. I'm a MSSQL veteran of 25 years, I think I'm suffering from "waah it's different"

Comment: @PeterWone: it has supported CTEs for over a decade (since 8.4). A data modifying CTEs nearly as long (since 9.0)